# Drag'n Drop Image editor Javascript

Tags: javascript, editor

I'm developing a web app and I like to make an editor just like this one 
[polyvore](http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app)

I've seen here is a similar (almost the same) question, and the answer is good, but I searched, and tried what the answer says, and I can't fine a good library for it.

What can I use? What libraries are there?

Note: I need to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a similar application now, and using jQuery with jQuery UI for the features like Drag/Drop. Functional part of the editor I've developed myself, check the working demo at http://labs.antaranian.me and if it is what you need, let me know, I'll help you during the development.